# Gerschgorin's Disks of a 3x3 complex matrix (2)

Tags: matrices

Take the following matrix as an example,
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & -i & 0 \\
 \frac{i}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & i & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
The eigenvalues are ${-1.37,  1, 0.37}$, and the plot of the Gerschgorin's disks is:
[image]

We see that each of the disks owns its eigenvalue. Take a second example:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & -i & 0 \\
 \frac{i}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & i & i \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The eigenvalues are ${-1.37,  i, 0.37}$, and the plot of the Gerschgorin's disks is:
[image]

Again we see that each of the disks owns its eigenvalue. Take a third example:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 &  i & 0 \\
 \frac{i}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -i & -i \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
The eigenvalues are ${  -i, -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i}{2}, -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{i}{2} }$, and the plot of the Gerschgorin's disks is:
[image]

We see that one of the disks doesn't own an eigenvalue. My question is how to tell when each disk own its eigenvalue, and under what condition a disk doesn't own its  eigenvalue. And any reference for more details about Gerschgorin's disks?

Comment: One handy fact about the Gerschgorin disks is that each connected collection of disks has the number of eigenvalues equal to the number of disks- if you have two disjoint collections, one of 3 circles and the other of 2, they will have 3 and 2 eigenvalues respectively. This gives a sufficient condition, in your notation, for each to "own" its eigenvalue; they are all pairwise disjoint.